# Generic Efficient String Comparison python for voice assistant

Tags: python, string-comparison, voice, assistant

I want to write my own voice assistant in python. 
The conversion from speech to text is solved, but now I want to compare strings efficiently.

Thereby the code should be written **as generic as possible**. 
Lets say I want to greet a guest with his name. I am going to say: "Hey Jarvis, greet my friend Lars." but the code for it should not be hard coded on lars and other names but on every name. I think this would be possible with regular expressions, but here comes the clue.

As I expect my software to become relatively larger, 
I may need to **compare hundreds of generic regular expressions**. 
This is too much time for a system which should ease my life (not make me spend more time).

Do you have any advice for me?

I thought about using sets, but I do not know how to integrate regular expression in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought about using sets, but I do not know how to integrate regular expression in them.

Here is how:

```
import re

s = {'Today','is','my','lucky','day,','because','today','is','Thanksgiving','day!'}
s = ' '.join(s)
print(re.findall(r'[A-Z]',s)) # Find all the capital letters in this example
```

Output:

```
['T', 'T']
```